# What happens if a method has a parameter of type char, but you pass it an int?

Tags: java

the title pretty much explains it. What happens if say you have

methodName(char c){
...
}

but you put an int in it instead of a char. whats going on in the method?

Comment: Nothing.  It doesn't compile.

Comment: Why don't you try this with actual code, and then if you still have a question come back here and update.

Comment: Why waste your time posting on the Internet, and waiting possibly forever for a possibly incorrect answer, when you can check for yourself in about 30 seconds, and get an answer that *must* be correct?

Comment: Try it the other way! Pass a `char` when it asks for an `int`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Try it why?

Comment: @EJP To learn something new?

Comment: @ElliotFrisch Such as what?

Comment: @EJP Sorry, two 't's. There is some value in learning the difference between a permitted widening conversion and a narrowing conversion that requires a cast (and why). It was a comment. And trying it both ways could be done in under a minute?

Answer (score 2):

You'll get a Compile time error.

Usually java is pretty good about this kind of thing, and even the most basic IDE's should spot this one for you.

I suggest you test this out on something like [this online java compiler.](https://www.compilejava.net/)